# Why does "echo -n ok >file" write a 6-byte file?

Tags: shell

i want to create a file with only 2 bytes and having as a text "00"

when I run the command `echo -n ok > myFile` to have just 2 bytes in 'myFile' I get 6 bytes after running the `ls -l`

In fact it shows me in the byte section that I have 6 bytes but I want to just 2 bytes.

Comment: Works for me, and generates a 2 byte file. So you may want to include information about your operation system.

Comment: If it works for MTilisted and not for you, then I suggest you run od against it and check the  output.

Comment: It also works for me in another computer but when I change the computer it doesn't. And for the output of the file it shows something like this : -n 42 like if the parameter n doesn't work it just puts directly '-n 42'

Comment: You don't appear to be using `bash`. The `-n` is being treated as ordinary text, not an option to suppress the newline, so you get `-`, `n`, `<space>`, `4`, `2`, and `\n` as your six ASCII characters.

Comment: `printf ok > myFile` should work (assuming a POSIX-like environment).

Comment: @chepner, ...one could get this behavior in bash, if both `xpg_echo` and `posix` flags are set. Granted, using a non-bash shell is more likely.

Comment: Examining the contents of the 6-byte file after you created it would have told you what's going on. So would running `echo -n ok` without redirecting its output.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Pretty sure virtually anyone the would have those flags set already knows why `echo -n` doesn't suppress a newline :)

Comment: @OtO : Do a `echo -n ok|xxd` and specify the shell you are using.

Comment: @chepner: As far I can see, the OP never claimed he was using bash. If s/he tagged the question correctly, we have here just plain POSIX shell.

Comment: @user1934428 Whether the OP thought they were using `bash` or just thought that `-n` was universal, my claim is still true (modulo the `xpg_echo` and `posix` options not being set).

Answer (score 1):

Use `printf`:

```
printf '%s' ok >myFile
```

...or more simply (but less reliably, as this doesn't always work right if your `ok` is instead a string with `%`s, literal backslashes, etc):

```
printf ok >myFile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `dd` utility

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=twobytes.txt count=2 bs=1
2+0 records in
2+0 records out
2 bytes copied, 0.000128232 s, 15.6 kB/s

cat twobytes.txt | hexdump 
0000000 0000                                   
0000002

ls -l twobytes.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 lmc users 2 Aug  4 17:39 twobytes.txt
```

This would also work (thanks @CharlesDuffy)

```
tr -d '\n' <<<'00' > twobytes.txt
```

Not recommended as `echo` behavior might differ in some implementation (see comments below)

```
echo -ne "\060\060" > twobytes.txt
```

Comment: `echo -ne` is not guaranteed to work, or to have any specific behavior _at all_. See the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of [the POSIX standard for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)

Comment: ...when `-n` is passed, the POSIX standard stops guaranteeing what `echo` will do -- it becomes implementation-defined. And supporting `-e` as an instruction to do anything but print `-e` on output is outright standard-noncompliant behavior.

Comment: See the excellent answer by Stephane on [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65807/3113) at [unix.se]

Comment: Also, note that _even if the shell is certain to be bash_, how echo behaves depends on active runtime flags -- whether the `xpg_echo` flag is active, and whether the `posix` flag is set. In some modes, even bash will make `echo -en ok` print `-en ok` instead of just `ok`.

Comment: See https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/OrangeAbandonedGreyware#main.sh demonstrating `echo -ne "\060\060" > twobytes.txt` creating a 7-byte file.

Comment: (note re: updated verbiage: because POSIX doesn't require or permit echo to support `-e`, it's more a concern about the command being _too_ POSIX-compliant, rather than not POSIX-compliant enough; it's rare for POSIX to prohibit extra flags from being added, but `echo` is a place -- the only one I know of offhand -- where it happens).

Comment: Also, you don't really need the `cat`. Consider `tr -d '\n' <<<'00' >twobytes.txt` as a replacement for the `tr` example.